# How to check email id already exists or not using yup validation?

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup

I am making a Login page in React application where i submit the email and password to the api.Now i want to know that is entered email is already exists or not using yup validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, is possible, bellow I will show how I did it checking on my MongoDB Atlas:

```
checkEmail: Yup.boolean(),
email: Yup.string()
  .email("Email should be valid and contain @")
  .required("Email is required")
  .when("checkEmail", {
    is: true,
    then: Yup.string()
    .test({
      message: () => "Email already exists",
      test: async (values) => {
        if (values) {
          try {
            let response = await fetch("http://localhost:3005/users/check", {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({ email: values }),
            });
            if (response.ok) {
              return true;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
      },
    }),
    
  }),
```

On the field email inside my callback onBlur I set manually the value of checkEmail which was false in my Initial Value as bellow:

```
                onBlur={(e) => {
                      props.handleBlur(e);
                      if (!props.errors.email) {
                        props.setValues({
                          ...values,
                          checkEmail: true,
                         })
                        }
                      }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sure there's no way of checking this using yup. However, you can just search in your db for the email the user entered. If nothing was found, the email doesn't already exist.